# How to create a summary statistics table for transformed variables in r

Tags: r, statistics, regression, summary

I want to create a summary statistics table in r for transformed variables. The variables are X, Y and Z. These variables have their original values. A summary statistics table can be created in R like this:

```
dataSumStatTable <- my.dataframe %>% select(X,Y,Z) 

sum1 <- sumtable(dataSumStatTable, 
         summ=c('min(x)','mean(x)','max(x)','sd(x)','notNA(x)'),
         title="Summary Statistics",
         summ.names=c('Min','Mean','Max','SD','Observations'),
         col.align=c('center','center','center', 'center', 'center'),
         labels=c('X',
                  'Y',
                  'Z',
         group.long = TRUE,
         digits = 2,
         fixed.digits = TRUE,
         align = TRUE,
         out = "viewer")
```

However, I am using these variables in regression models where all variables are in log. How can I create a summary statistics table for my variables in log?

Comment: Would it work if you mutated X, Y, Z yourself to their log values before calling these statistics?

Comment: Yes,  I've tried it manually and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `log` on the data you want to summarise first.

For example:

Untransformed summary:

```
> mtcars |> select(hp, drat, wt) |> summary()
       hp             drat             wt       
 Min.   : 52.0   Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513  
 1st Qu.: 96.5   1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581  
 Median :123.0   Median :3.695   Median :3.325  
 Mean   :146.7   Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217  
 3rd Qu.:180.0   3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610  
 Max.   :335.0   Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424
```

Tranformed:

```
> mtcars |> select(hp, drat, wt) |> log() |> summary()
       hp             drat             wt        
 Min.   :3.951   Min.   :1.015   Min.   :0.4141  
 1st Qu.:4.570   1st Qu.:1.125   1st Qu.:0.9479  
 Median :4.812   Median :1.307   Median :1.2009  
 Mean   :4.882   Mean   :1.269   Mean   :1.1217  
 3rd Qu.:5.193   3rd Qu.:1.366   3rd Qu.:1.2835  
 Max.   :5.814   Max.   :1.595   Max.   :1.6908
```